# How to get rid of several method calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the `Search` class where I have a method that processes the request and returns the user ids.

also, I have three methods which are based on the number of results, they would be to count the number of users in a particular category.

but it turns out that I have to call method `base_lead_scope` 4 times, is it possible to get rid of it?

```
def initialize(opts = {})
  opts.symbolize_keys!
  @params = opts[:params]
  @current_team = opts[:current_team]
  @current_user = opts[:current_user]
  @scope = base_lead_scope(opts[:overrides] || {})
end

def archived_count
  @archived_count ||= base_lead_scope(overrides: { archived: true })
                                      .including_referrals(user: current_user, team: current_team)
                                      .archived.total_count
end

def recruiting_count
  @recruiting_count ||= base_lead_scope(overrides: { archived: false })
                                        .including_referrals(user: current_user, team: current_team)
                                        .recruiting_status.total_count
end

def retention_count
  @retention_count ||= base_lead_scope(overrides: { archived: false })
                                        .including_referrals(user: current_user, team: current_team)
                                        .retention_status.total_count
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it as,

```
def get_count_of(status)
  @archived_count ||= base_lead_scope(overrides: { archived: (status == :archieved ? true : false) })
    .including_referrals(user: current_user, team: current_team)
    .public_send(status)
    .total_count
end
```

So you can pass these attributes in status argument as below,

```
get_count_of(:archived)
get_count_of(:recruiting_status)
get_count_of(:retention_status)
```

Comment: but what to do with the method arguments? `overrides: { archived: true }` or `false`